# How to reestablish the default library of an R project after updating Ubuntu?

Tags: r, linux

I´m developing an R package in RStudio and a set a local library to contain all my packages. After installing some updates in my Ubuntu system, it seems that my R Project have lost track of the local library and is unable to load the libraries that were associated with it. If I try to Build & Reload the package with

```
R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source mypackage
```

The program tries to install to library '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/' which is rejected with:

```
ERROR: No permission to install to directory '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/'
```

As far as I remember, whenever I rebuilt my package, that line pointed to my local directory, where all my libraries were localted

```
installing to library ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
```

It is clear that somehow R have lost track of the connection between the project and the libraries.

I tried re-including the path with

```
.LibPaths("/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2")
```

but, just after I rebuild the package again, the program created a 3.3 directory in x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library. From there, it is unable to find the libraries that are associated to my program and throws another error:

```
ERROR: dependencies '...', '...' are not available for package "mypackage"
```

Is there a way to restore the program to the way it was before so I don't have to reinstall everything and start from scratch?

Comment: did my answer provide any help on this? If it did, please accept it. If not, how did you work around it? Others may want to know.

Answer (score 1):

By default, R adds the major-minor version numbers to the library path ([`?.libPaths`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html)) for a good reason, assuming that the jump from 3.2 to 3.3 introduced efficiencies or incompatibilities. It is implied that this version jump requires new installation of packages.

If you override this, packages assembled in 3.2 may not always play nicely in 3.3. (I'm not going to test this theory, please report back if you can disprove this statement, I'm honestly interested!)

BTW: your call to `.libPaths` seems suspect: I don't know of a capital-L version, and when calling it you should include the previous path (unless you truly mean to omit the system R library paths entirely), such as:

```
.libPaths("/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2", .libPaths())
```

If you choose to do that, any bugs you may find in others' packages are possibly due to that incompatibility and should not necessarily be reported to developers.

Another option would be to re-install all packages from your 3.2 installation into your 3.3 library path. Something like this should help automate the process:

```
# to reinstall packages installed in R-3.2 subdir into R-3.3
install.packages(list.files(path = "~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2"))
```